# Lazyweb: Need javascript that removes li elements based on visited class of a element

Tags: javascript, css, greasemonkey

I've got this page which has a lot of data I don't need, as I've already clicked on it, but it repeats often so I have to visually look for blue.  I realized this could be more efficient, and asked a CSS friend if I could set the element to hidden based on whether or not the containing link has been visited.  Apparently you need js for that.

Tree that results in removal (or visibility:none) of the li.result element:

```
li.result
 div.avatar
  a
```

I'm trying to figure out how to do this via googling, and got something on Expert Sex Change that didn't help much.  How would you do it?

**This is for Greasemonkey, so tips that involve adding code to the page and checking cookies are useless**.  I apologize for not making this clearer than just tagging the post greasemonkey before.

Comment: I think the real problem with that is to determine via javascript the state of the anchor, the 'visited' isn't a real class, but a pseudo-class

Answer (score 4):

1.You could use the a:visited css selector.

```
a:visited{
   display:none;
}
```

And it will hide visited links (at least in firefox).

2.If you want to remove the div and li above that, you would probably need to use a cookie and remember what links the user clicked.

So :

when a user clicks a link, put that link Id in the cookie. 
Then , for every link id in the cookie, you could do with [jQuery](http://jquery.com) something like :

```
var ids = $.cookie("cookie_with_ids");
var split_ids = ids.split(','); // split by comma

for(var i= 0; i<split_ids.length; i++){
    $("link_"+split_ids[i]).parent().parent().hide();
}
```

The html should look something like :

```
<li class="result">
 <div class="avatar">
  <a href="#" id="unique_link_id_on_this_page"> ....
```

This is not tested by any means, but it should give you an ideea about what you have to do.

For cookie handling you could use the [jquery cookie plugin](http://www.stilbuero.de/2006/09/17/cookie-plugin-for-jquery/)

Comment: By "the first method" do you mean the CSS trick which will hide the avatar but not the line item nor the rest of the stuff in the line item?

Also, I guess I should have made it more clear than just sticking it in a tag: this is for greasemonkey. I don't own the site.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that I haven't used Greasemonkey before and my JS knowledge is simplistic at best.

Couldn't you add a style declaration to either the existing `<style>` tag or the `<head>` using JavaScript?

For example, add a rule that applies different colours to different links:

```
li.result div.avatar a {
    color: #000;
}

li.result div.avatar a:visited {
    color: #111;
}
```

Then traverse through all `li` elements classed `result`, checking if the `a` contained within it has a colour of `#000` or `#111`. In my mind that would create a basic :visited checker. I'm going to have to test it now (if only to learn something) but is this kind of thing viable?

Comment: Technically I could use stylish to change the CSS of a page, the problem is CSS doesn't do the 'if then' things required to remove the whole line item based on the visited selector of an anchor inside a div. I'm doing it on results for search.twitter.com if that helps you test.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the one a friend whipped up for me that works perfectly.  Mainly posting in case someone else ends up finding it useful.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Twitter Search Seen
// @namespace      http://ctho.org
// @description    Hides tweets you've seen
// @include        http://search.twitter.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

for each (var i in document.links) {
    if (i.parentNode.className == "msg" && i == i.parentNode.childNodes[1]) {
//alert(getComputedStyle(i, null).color);break;
        if (getComputedStyle(i, null).color == "rgb(147, 13, 133)") {
            i.parentNode.parentNode.style.display="none";       
        } 
    }
}
```

Hackish, yeah, you could theoretically use stylish to set visited links to a known color as well.